# java mail API forwarding the mail functionality

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am developing a standalone java utility which will connect to a existing mailbox of any organization and will read/check  the mails from Inbox that if any mail’s address field (“TO and CC” ) is crossing the character limits of 2000 characters or not….if it is crossing the limits then it will forward the same mail an email id else will do nothing….i have written the code for forwarding the mail functionality given below... it is working good...mail is getting forwarded but it is showing an exception ….
please suggest where I am lacking….

```
public class ForwardMail {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
          properties.put("mail.pop3s.host", "mailcluster.mycompany.com");
          properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
          properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); /* may be commented later*/
          properties.put("smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mailcluster.mycompany.com");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        //  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
          Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("myname@mycompany.com","mypassword@123");  
                }  
              });
     try{
         // session.setDebug(true);
         // Get a Store object and connect to the current host
         Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
         store.connect("mailcluster.mycompany.com", "myname@mycompany.com","mypassword@123");


         // Create a Folder object and open the folder
         Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
         folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
         if (messages.length != 0) {

         for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            // Get all the information from the message
           // String from = InternetAddress.toString(message.getFrom());
            String from = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            if (from != null) {
               System.out.println("From:"  + from);
            }
            /*String replyTo = InternetAddress.toString(message.getReplyTo());
            if (replyTo != null) {
               System.out.println("Reply-to: " + replyTo);
            }*/
            String to = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            if (to != null) {
               System.out.println("To: " + to);
            }

            String subject = message.getSubject();
            if (subject != null) {
               System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
            }
            /*Date sent = message.getSentDate();
            if (sent != null) {
               System.out.println("Sent: " + sent);
            }*/
            System.out.print("Do you want to reply [y/n] : ");
            String ans = reader.readLine();
            if ("Y".equals(ans) || "y".equals(ans)) {
               Message forward = new MimeMessage(session);
               // Fill in header
               forward.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(from));
               forward.setSubject("Fwd: " + message.getSubject());
               forward.setFrom(new InternetAddress(to));

               // Create the message part
               MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
               // Create a multipart message
               Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
               // set content
               messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "message/rfc822");
               // Add part to multi part
               multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
               // Associate multi-part with message
               forward.setContent(multipart);
               forward.saveChanges();
               // Transport.send(forward);
               // Send the message by authenticating the SMTP server
               // Create a Transport instance and call the sendMessage
               Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
               try {
                  //connect to the smpt server using transport instance
                  t.connect("myname@mycompany.com", "mypassword@123");
                  t.sendMessage(forward, forward.getAllRecipients());

               } finally {
                  t.close();
               }

               System.out.println("message forwarded successfully....");

            // close the store and folder objects
            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
            }// end if

         }// end for
   }// end if
     }   catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();  
    }
        }
    }
```

---

following is exception i am getting..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Folder is not Open
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.checkOpen(POP3Folder.java:551)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.getProtocol(POP3Folder.java:581)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.loadHeaders(POP3Message.java:606)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.getHeader(POP3Message.java:383)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:701)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getRecipients(MimeMessage.java:534)
at servion.ForwardMail.main(ForwardMail.java:56)
```

How to remove this exception ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the folder after processing one message, which means it's closed while you're accessing the Message object for the second message, so JavaMail can't get the message data from the server.

And while you're fixing that, be sure to fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Finally, the `"smtp.starttls.enable"` property should be `"mail.smtp.starttls.enable"`.

Comment: adding "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" is giving error whereas earlier is working  fine...howerver  adding  folder.close(false); after finishing for loop is solving the problem but mail is getting forwarded twice which is even big trouble....

Comment: If adding mail.smtp.starttls.enable is giving an error, that must mean your server isn't supporting STARTTLS properly, or there's something else wrong with your configuration.  In any event, you can remove the bogus "smtp.starttls.enable" property because JavaMail isn't looking at it at all.